# how to retrieve picture in picture box from SQL?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add image with its filename and file path in picture box from SQL but i am getting error "unable to cast system.string to system.byte". how can i do this?

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

```
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("server= .\SQLEXPRESS; database = billing software; integrated security=true")

    Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from stockimagedata where imageid = @imageid", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@imageid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox4.Text

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    adapter.Fill(table)


    TextBox4.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
        TextBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
        TextBox5.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()

    Dim img() As Byte

    img = table.Rows(0)(2)

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)

    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)




End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting `TextBox5.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()`, so `table.Rows(0)(2)` is a string type; then `img = table.Rows(0)(2)`. Does this column actually contain the path to an Image file? If so, then `PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(table.Rows(0)(2))))`. Assuming that the path represents a full path, not a file name.

Comment: my textbox5.text = D:\SavedImages\20150905_205345.jpg. but it is giving error.

Comment: Well, then it's a full path. If that path points to an existing Image file, then you can use the code in my previous comment. You just forgot `File.ReadAllBytes()`: this method reads all the bytes from a file and returns a bytes array that you can pass to the `MemoryStream` constuctor. I forgot to add `.ToString()` to `table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()`, probably

Comment: do you mean this  PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(table.Rows(0)(2).ToString())). but it is not working. its showing same error

Comment: Nope. You're still missing `File.ReadAllBytes()`. Read again my first comment

Comment: ok thanks its working now.i removed  Dim img() As Byte

    img = table.Rows(0)(2)

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img) and paste your code